# Continues mongo db querying gets slower

Tags: php, mongodb, performance, mongodb-query

I'm running a tool that runs on a mongo collection with 7,766,558 documents in following template.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53f602685a38d0bf5e8c6df1"),
    "ids" : "5667",
    "h" : [ 
        {
            "s" : "Briefly, 36 h following transfection, the cells were harvested and lysed in 500 µL HTE buffer containing calcium or calcium chelating reagents according to the experimental condition (150 mM NaCl, 20 mM HEPES (pH 7.4), 50 mM NaF, 1 mM Na3VO4, 1% Triton X-100 and 5 mM EDTA + 5 mM EGTA or 100 µM CaCl2 and complete protease inhibitor cocktail (Roche Applied Science)).",
            "p" : "roche"
        }
    ],
    "ct" : 1445951888.0000000000000000
}
```

What the query does is filters the documents on `"ids"` (supplier id) and `"ct"` (created date) > [given date] and then run a mongo regex match on "h.s". Three instances of this job runs on 3 threads on a given time which each process difference suppliers. At the start of these threads, all 3 runs their queries quite fast. But the longer they run (approximately after 12 hours or so) the querying tend to get slower and slower.

The query that i'm running is

```
db.collection.find({'ids':4296, 'ct':{"$gte":1455062400}, 'h.s':{       '$regex': "/[^a-zA-Z]" . $catalogId . "[^0-9a-zA-Z]/i" }})
```

the solution doesn't throw any errors. The problem i'm facing is that the time that the query takes to perform drastically drops based on time. If the tool query 10 times per second at start. after like 10-12 hours its only around 5 times per second.

Any ideas into any performance updates i could do to over come this?

Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That's the text you will get presented with when your question gets put on hold. It inevitably "should" be, since you don't actually include any query or code that your process is actually running or what it's conclusion should be. So if you want help to find a better solution, then you need to proide us something to show what you are actually doing,

Comment: The query that i'm running is db.collection.find({'ids':4296, 'ct':{"$gte":1455062400}, 'h.s':{ '$regex': "/[^a-zA-Z]" . $catalogId . "[^0-9a-zA-Z]/i" }})

the solution doesn't throw any errors. As I've mentioned in the question, the problem i'm facing is that the time that the query takes to perform drastically drops based on time. If the tool query 10 times per second at start. after like 10-12 hours its only around 5 times per second.

Comment: There is an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36326237/edit) link on your question. Use it to add detail. Don't post code and other details in comments. It detracts and it is not very readable. Also clearly `$catalogId` is a variable and probably sourced in a "loop". That's why the ask here to to show the code in context. Get editing.

Comment: Have you considered to extract any potential catalog-Id's to a separate array-field of your document when you insert them? You could then create an index on that array and query it without a regular expression, which would increase the speed a lot.